# How to do dynamic Helpcontext with anchor scroll in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Here I created a sample for a dynamic Help Context. Based on the page it will load dynamic help data which is working fine.

In local `$anchorScroll` is also working fine.

What I need exactly is while I click the help button I need to set `anchorScroll` id inside this function `$scope.HelpFunction`. Can any one help me on this.

```
example
```

[Sample Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/CnBCvnLeTtOHWPx4cShT?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to do something like in [this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/YqmJMxmCPLDVRchLAa58?p=preview) which is a fork of yours. Click home link then click the help button; it should scroll to foo4.

I changed your service from:

```
.service('myService', function() {
            var data = {};
            return{
                setData: function(val){
                    return val;
                }
            }
            if(data == {})
            {
                console.log("inside")
                data = {'a':'foo1'};
            }
            console.log(data)
            return data;
        })
```

to

```
app.service('myService', function() {
            var data = {};
            return{
              data: data,
              setData: function(key, val){
                    data[key] = val;
                }
            }
        });
```

As that was the malfunctioning part of your code (no api to access the `data` object).

Also since objects are passed by reference in JavaScript, you don't need a setter on data, you can do direct assignments. Moreover, instead of a service you can also just use a [angular value provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) and inject that as a dependency where you want to share that object between different components of your app.

Comment: can you give me ranable sample? @gkc